# Rear defrost lines

Tags: vw

Will removing a bad tint job damage my rear defrost lines? Recently decided to finally remove the film I have on my windows due to poor quality (they didn’t last long)

Answer (score 3):

Usually, no, but if the defrost lines were originally in bad condition then there is a risk...

Test on a small area, and perhaps gently warm the tint film as it is removed.

Comment: Would a hair dryer work for that or would you need a heat gun @SolarMike?

Comment: @GdG For that a hair dryer on low would be sufficient - heat guns are more powerful, but only need to gently warm...

Comment: The car is basically new so I don’t believe the lines are in bad shape I’m going to get them professionally taken off and redone at a different location. My own fault for going quantity over quality